# Header rule exactly at margin

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr

I would like the header rule to be exactly positioned at the margin. The default `includehead` option (e.g. `\usepackage[margin=1in, includehead]{geometry}`) seems to position the top of the header text at the 'original' margin. How might one position the headrule exactly at the 'original' margin (along with the appropriate shift in the header text)?

**Edit:** I would like to maintain separation between the main text and the header rule.

What more precise solutions are there?

**Edit 3:** Example of desired layout using `\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, top=2.92cm, headsep= 0.5cm]{geometry}`: [image]

The standard layout of a fancy header does not seem to have the rule on the margin, whether or not `includehead` is used. The image I have is the 'desired' one where the header rule is approximately at the margin. Similar can be achieved without `includehead` e.g. by using `\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, top=3.15cm]{geometry}`. These are estimates. **Note: when I mean rule at the margin I mean the 'original' marginal (e.g. 2.5 cm all sides) before the shift in margin that accompanies the vertical downward shift in main text.** However, I am wondering If there is a precise way to achieve this that works for all font sizes and margin sizes automatically (instead of using ean approximate `top=3.15cm` for 2.5cm margins only).

**Edit 4:** With markings. Note text is random text from a Wikiepdia page. Example[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twoside, openany]{book}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, top=2.92cm, headsep=0.5cm]{geometry} % <- want a more precise/better solution
% \usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, top=3.15cm]{geometry} % or this

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{hi}
\lhead{hi}

\begin{document}

Hello

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try adding `headsep=0pt` to your list of [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry) options. That leaves no gap between the header and the text, putting the header rule exactly at the top of the text margin. Is this what you're after?

Comment: While that does seem to put the rule at the margin, the body text then 'touches' the rule. How to get the start of the body text to vertically shift as well? i.e. separation between body text and the rule

Comment: Choose some small value like `headsep=.5ex`, or `headsep=5pt`.

Comment: That is a work around, but I would prefer to retain the normal separation or have any separation of my choice with the headrule still exactly at the margin.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the way the header rule is set, shifting it down to be just above the text block's top margin:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\rhead{hi}% Right header
\lhead{hi}% Left header

% Update \headrule to be on the (top) text margin
\makeatletter
\def\headrule{{%
  \if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
  \vskip\headsep% Move down to the top of the text block
  \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth% Set the header rule
  \vskip\dimexpr-\headrulewidth-\headsep\relax% Move up to the header
}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not quite as I had in mind. I would like to imitate `\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, top=2.92cm, headsep= 0.5cm]{geometry}`. How to achieve this?

Comment: @humbadambadam: My answer does the trick for any `geometry` setting. If it doesn't, can you include a picture of what you want *exactly*?

Comment: Have included an image in an Edit.

Comment: @humbadambadam: The image you should has the standard layout of a fancy header, with a gap between the text block and the header, together with the rule underneath the header. So what should change in that image to obtain the result you're after?

Comment: The standard layout of a fancy header does not seem to have the rule on the margin, whether or not `includehead` is used. The image I have is the 'desired' one where the header rule is approximately at the margin, achieved by using `top=2.92cm`. The `headsep=0.5cm` shifts the main text up closer to the rule which is now at the margin. However, I am wondering If there is a precise way to achieve this that works for all font sizes and margin sizes automatically (instead of using `top=2.92cm` for 2.5cm margins)

Comment: Mistake above: `top=2.92cm` AND `headsep=0.5cm` puts the rule at the margin. `top=3.15cm` itself achieves this: `\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, top=3.15cm]{geometry}`. These are estimates.

Comment: @humbadambadam: When you adjust `top`, the text block dimensions change with it, so it makes little sense to say the "desired" layout has the header rule approximately at the margin. If you add the `showframe` option, you'll see how the text block and header is surrounded by a box. So, again, can you include a drawing of what you want *exactly*. You can use Paint to move graphics elements around so it's more clear where you want the rule to go.

Comment: Sorry, I may have been unclear. I meant that the rule should be at the 'original' margin. I have included a picture.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the header rule as you want changing the approach. I used the `xcoffin` package that allows, very easily,  to place any stuff anywhere in the page. In this case a rule, `color= blue, width = 1pt, length =\textwidth+\oddsidemargin+1in`.  (for the `\oddsidemargin`).

The rules are typeset before/after the left/right header and shifted down by adding a proper Y offset:`1ex` down.

Please check the proper alignment using the `showframe` package.

You can set the  `headsep` as you want (I put 2cm to exaggerate the result) provided that you set the `top` value = `1in +headsep` to have the header rule 1in from to top of the paper page. Use the `layout` package to check de values.

As you see, the position of the header rules, in the header, are independent of any setting in `geometry`.

This is the code for  a more realistic scenario of a book, with different odd and even margins, and in my understanding that you want the rules extending towards the outer margin of the book (where the page number is located). Easy to change otherwise.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twoside, openany]{book}

\usepackage[left=5.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, top=4.54cm, headsep=2cm]{geometry} % top= 1in + headsep

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\TypesetCoffin\Framexi hleft}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage }
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{hright\TypesetCoffin\Framexii }
    
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % width of line bellow the header

\usepackage{xcoffins,calc,xcolor} % added

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text

%   \usepackage{showframe}  %added
%   \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}    %added
\usepackage{layout} %added

\NewCoffin\Framexi
\NewCoffin\Framexii
\NewCoffin\Hrulei
\NewCoffin\Hruleii

\SetHorizontalCoffin\Hrulei{\color{blue}\rule{\textwidth+\oddsidemargin+1in}{1pt}} % lenght and width of the rule   
\SetHorizontalCoffin\Hruleii{\color{blue}\rule{\paperwidth -1in -\evensidemargin}{1pt}}

\JoinCoffins*\Framexi[l,vc]\Hrulei[l,vc](0pt,-1ex) % X Y offsets
\JoinCoffins*\Framexii[l,vc]\Hruleii[r,vc](0pt,-1ex) % X Y offsets
    
\begin{document}
%\layout  %check the layout

\kant[1-20] 
    
\end{document}
```

[image: one]

[image: two]

[image: three]